# Is 641 the Smallest Factor of any Composite Fermat Number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

Consider the sequence $a_n = 2^{2^n}+1$ of so-called Fermat numbers. It's well known that $a_5$ isn't prime ($a_5 = 641 \cdot 6700417$, this is due to Euler). What I want to know about this sequence is the smallest factor of any of its composite terms. Is it simply 641, or does a later composite term in the sequence have a smaller factor?

I originally wanted to ask if there had been any effort to solve similar problems for other sequences as well, but that's not something I feel MSE would want. If someone has any info on this, however, they should feel free to comment or add it to their answer!

Comment: Also see [A023394](https://oeis.org/A023394) where all terms below $10^{19}$ are given.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $q$ is a prime factor of $a_n=2^{2^n}+1$, then $q\equiv1\pmod{2^{n+1}}$ and hence
$$q>2^{n+1}\ .$$
So if we are looking for $q<641$ then $n\le8$; if we want $a_n$ composite then $n\ge5$.  Thus $n=5,6,7,8$, and there is no prime factor $q$ less than $641$, because [all these numbers have been completely factorised](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatNumber.html).

Comment: How do you know that $q\equiv \pmod {2^{n+1}}$? I can see that $a_n=qk\equiv \pmod {2^{n+1}}$, but why does the integer $k$ have to be the inverse of $q\pmod {2^{n+1}}$?

Comment: @mathh This is a standard result about Fermat numbers.  Here is a quick proof: modulo $q$ we have $2^{2^{n+1}}\equiv1$ but $2^{2^n}\not\equiv1$; therefore the order of $2$ is a factor of $2^{n+1}$ but not a factor of $2^n$; therefore the order is $2^{n+1}$.  But since $q$ is prime, the order of any element is a factor of $q-1$.

Comment: In fact, Lucas (in 1878) strengthened the result to $q\equiv1\pmod{2^{n+2}}$. See [MathWorld (Weisstein)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatNumber.html). [Other sources (Caldwell)](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/FermatDivisor.html) say Euler already knew this, but I think it was Lucas.

Answer (score 3):

There is a deterministic answer to this, easy computer program. For each prime $p$ of interest, calculate 
$$ 2,4,16,256,\ldots, 2^{\left( 2^n \right)}, \ldots \pmod p  $$ until you find repetition. For the prime being worked on, this tells you whether $2^{\left( 2^n \right)}$ can ever be congruent to $-1 \pmod p.$